# Cannot SaveAs an excel file in c# without it giving a read-only error?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio, interop

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

        xlAppDestination = new Excel.Application();
        xlAppDestination.DisplayAlerts = false;
        xlWorkBookDestination = xlAppDestination.Workbooks.Open(fileNameDestination, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheetDestination = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBookDestination.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        rangeDestination = xlWorkSheetDestination.UsedRange;

        rangeDestination.Cells[1, 1] = (string)(range.Cells[14, 3] as Excel.Range).Text.ToString();
        textBox1.Text = fileNameDestination;

        //xlAppDestination.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
        xlWorkBookDestination.SaveAs(fileNameDestination);
        xlWorkBookDestination.Close(0);
        xlWorkBook.Close(0);


        xlCleanup();
    }
```

I am trying to open one excel file, and transfer information from that file into another excel file, the destination excel file. The only problem is when it comes to saving. I open the destination file as not read-only, but when I try to saveas, it says that it is read-only. I make sure there are no extra excel tasks running in the background, it still happens. It works when I use save, but it does not reliably save over the destination file in the same location. I have yet to determine what pattern it takes, but I need to be able to overwrite the destination file in the same place every time, as this will be appending to old excel files that already exist. No matter what I do to the saveas statement, it always throws me back the read-only argument.

EDIT- I've tried to use the .Save() option, and turn off alerts. But instead of ignoring the alert to overwrite the destination file, it sticks it inside the Documents folder. Does anyone have experience with the behavior of the regular Save() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you right click on your excel file and check its properties to make sure the "Read-Only" property is not set?

Comment: It doesn't have that read-only property set. The test one is a blank workbook from Excel 2013. It just keeps saying it's read-only in the error message, when I've made sure to open it in a non-read-only way.

Answer (score 0):

rangeDestination.Cells[1, 1] = (string)(range.Cells[14, 3] as Excel.Range).Text.ToString();
        textBox1.Text = fileNameDestination & ".xls";

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this answer.

Comment: I had a poor answer. You are saving a string. That's a problem. You should open the workbook with if .enableevents=false then .enableevents=true, use the string content then add the extension.

Comment: I'm extremely confused by what you're saying. I pull string info from cell in one excel file into another cell in a different file. The fileNameDestination already has the full path, including the .xls extension. And I did try to set enableevents, but it had no effect that I could see. When I open the destination excel file, it tells me it has to open as read-only because it's being modified by someone else. How do I stop that so I can saveas properly?